# i have many div and i want to search/filter by textinput in js scripts by onkeyup and I Have more than 100 div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have more than 100 div elements, and I want to search/filter by textinput in js scripts by onkeyup.

```js
function crmenu() {
  var j, descc, filter, input, boxmenu, descc;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();

  boxmenu = document.getElementsByClassName("boxmenu");
  for (j = 0; j <      boxmenu.length; j++) {
    if (boxmenu.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      boxmenu[j].style.display = "";
    } else {
      boxmenu[j].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div.boxmenu {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  height: 170px;
}

div.boxmenu:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.boxmenu img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.titlemenu {
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row" style="padding-left:1px;">
  <div class="boxmenu">
    <a>
      <img src="" alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="titlemenu">material </div>
  </div>

  <div class="boxmenu">
    <a>
       <img src="" alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="titlemenu">Human Resource </div>
  </div>

  <div class="boxmenu">
    <a>
       <img src="" alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="titlemenu">Financial </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="crmenu ( ) " placeholder="search in input">
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it's basically just a typo where you have tried to use `boxmenu` without `[j]` in your `if` condition (but you do correctly have the `[j]` inside the if and else blocks). Fix that and it works.

Comment: To elaborate on @nnnnnn, using `getElementsByClassName` returns an array, so you're getting this error `TypeError: boxmenu.innerHTML is undefined` - you need select an individual element

Comment: Sorry i forgot to return the array value. boxmenu[j]. And thank you for reminding and helping